# How to write a function pointer with a parameter pack along with its expansion?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, variadic-templates

To my understanding the same thing is happening to `std::thread`'s constructor where the first parameter is the address of a function, and the rest are its parameters. I basically want the same thing with the constructor. After the syntax i would need a way to expand the pack from the parameters example. This is what i tried

```
template<typename... Args>
void fun(void (*funptr)(Args)...)
    {
        int value = sizeof...(Args);
        if (value > 0)
        {
            //Expansion Here
        }
    }
```

Comment: `void fun(void (*funptr)(Args)...)`->`void fun(void (*funptr)(Args...)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `template <typename... Args, typename... Ts>void fun(void (*funptr)(Args...), Ts&&... args) { funptr(std::forward<Ts>(args)...); }`?

Comment: I want to pass first a function pointer and the rest be any number of template parameters and how to expand the variadic pack